# How to filter idlist in command line when importing data via migration

Tags: migrations

I know I'm really missing something here. I have a custom migration source plugin that requires a query() to be returned.

If I pass an `--idlist=123` parameter with the import this query still runs on all of the nodes as there is no way to limit it dynamically. What am I missing?

The migration is supposed to query the legacy D7 db for content types (event) and then I need to update each result's fields in my prepareRow(). This works except that the query is always returning all events. I think I'm misunderstanding the need/purpose for the query() function.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue during migration. There are open issues in Drupal.org but they are not closed yet. But for now we have a work around to solve this issue.

```
public function query() {
    // Hack for getting idlist to filter in command line
    $idlist = NULL;
    foreach ($_SERVER['argv'] as $arg) {
      if (strpos($arg, '--idlist') === 0) {
        list(, $idlist) = explode('=', $arg);
        $idlist = explode(',', $idlist);
        break;
      }
    }
$query = $this->select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n')
  ->orderBy('nid', 'ASC');

if ($idlist) {
  $query->condition('n.nid', $idlist, 'IN');
}

return $query;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
drush migrate:import example_node_articles --update --idlist=1234
 [notice] Processed 1 item (0 created, 1 updated, 0 failed, 0 ignored) - done with 'example_node_articles'
```

Source : https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_tools/issues/3107400#comment-13428024